# How can I combine the first page of each pdf in a folder?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

How can I combine the first page of each pdf in a folder? If possible, I'd like to do that using a command line application. Currently I'm using the [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/) software using a command like this:

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output all.pdf
```

But I don't know how to combine only the first page of *each* pdf. I read about the `cat` arguments but I still don't know how to do that.

**UPDATE:**

The command:

```
pdftk *.pdf cat 1-2 output all.pdf
```

Gets the first two pages of the last pdf expanded by the `*.` shell operator...

**UPDATE 2**:

Managed to do I what I was looking for, but manually, so not using `*.` shell operator:

```
pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf cat 1 1 output combined.pdf
```

An *imaginary* shell script would look like:

```
pdftk *.pdf cat repeat(1, COUNT(*.pdf)) output combined.pdf

repeat(C, N) -> repeat the character C N times
COUNTOF(*.pdf) -> get the number of PDF files the folder
```

Comment: What OS? there's a probably workable windows answer, but it would be super neat if you were a little more precise about what OS you want to do this on

Comment: This one-liner would work on linux/Mac: `pdftk *.pdf cat \`python -c "print(' '.join('1' * $(ls *.pdf | wc -l)))"\` output combined.pdf`

Answer (score 2):

In the following command, the `-dFirstPage=1` and `-dLastPage=1` apply to each PDF individually, before concatenation:

```
gs -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf *.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

### How can I combine first page of each pdf in a folder?

Well, using [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) you can complete this via command line shell in Windows like so using a couple staging directories and a simple FOR loop to iterate the pdftk commands accordingly. . .

<sub>Please note that folder names with spaces need to be double quoted around the folder name and also have double backslash in the folder path as well. e.g. `D:\\"test folder"\\*.pdf`, `C:\Test\\"Output 1"`, and so forth.</sub>

### Batch Script

```
@ECHO ON

SET PDFDir=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test
SET newPDFDir=%PDFDir%\new
SET combinedDir=%newPDFDir%\combined

IF NOT EXIST "%newPDFDir%" MD "%newPDFDir%"
IF NOT EXIST "%combinedDir%" MD "%combinedDir%"
IF EXIST "%combinedDir%\*.pdf" DEL /Q /F "%combinedDir%\*.pdf"
IF EXIST "%newPDFDir%\*.pdf" DEL /Q /F "%newPDFDir%\*.pdf"

:IteratePDFtk
FOR %%F IN ("%PDFDir%\*.PDF") DO pdftk %%~F cat 1 output "%newPDFDir%\%%~NXF"
CD /D "%newPDFDir%"
pdftk %newPDFDir%\*.pdf cat output %combinedDir%\combined.pdf
EXPLORER "%combinedDir%"
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with your answer as written - it looks almost like OP's actually looking for a linux solution

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I used in Ubuntu Bionic as pdftk is not available any more:

`mkdir temp &&
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' -type f -exec bash -c 'qpdf --empty --pages "$1" 1 -- "temp/${1%.pdf}_1.pdf"' bash {} \; &&
qpdf --empty --pages temp/*.pdf -- out.pdf &&
rm -r temp`

Short description: 1) create a temp folder, 2) extract 1st page of each pdf file and store in the temp file, 3) combine all the files in that folder, and 4) delete that folder.

Comment: 1) Thanks. I did run it with an edit to address (3) and it still works. 3) Sure, I will add some explanation. 3) You are right, that was a limitation which can be fixed using -maxdepth option.

Comment: This solution does exactly what the OP asked for.  I needed that also, tyvm.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Ghostscript:

If the PDF file includes accents and spaces, open command terminal using Windows key + R
and  `cdm /U`. Add path in cdm.exe using

```
set path=C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.23\bin
```

Change directory

```
cd ...
```

create a list of file using (file name written between quotes because of spaces):

```
(for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b /s /c *.pdf') do @echo "%f") > file.txt
```

control in Notepad++ or simple Notepad that the file is correctly saved in UTF8, then

```
gswin32c -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf @file.txt
```